# How to change black edge into transparent edge using GDAL?

Tags: gdal

I am trying to make seaice map in the Arctic Ocean.

I used a code like this.

gdal_translate -outsize 100% 100% -a_nodata value -co format=png -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY input.tif output.kmz

However when I upload kmz file into Google Earth, there is black edge.

How can I transform black edge into transparent edge?

[image]

Comment: Is the original tiff perhaps jpeg compressed? Use gdalinfo for checking.

Comment: Hmm...original tiff file is png compressed. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I can't reproduce with my images. Could you share your source image or is it confidential?